# Duplicate column value in MYSQL query

Tags: mysql, sql, join, duplicates

I have a working knowledge of mysql only. Normally it is good enough but I am having problems with this query despite looking for an understandable solution online.

I have three tables:

**users**

```
user_id  
username
```

**product_to_users**

```
user_id (primary key)  
security_id (primary_key)
```

**product**

```
security_id (primary_key)  
product_name
```

I need to get the username associated with each product name.
I developed this query.

```
select username,product_name 
from users 
JOIN product_to_users ON users.user_id=product_to_users.user_id 
JOIN product ON product.security_id=product_to_users.security_id;
```

I try to create a link to each table, which works fine but I get

```
username      product_name   
bob           prod1   
bob           prod2
```

I need to eliminate duplicates in the left column so I need to get rid of the second bob.

My research revealed three things: a LEFT JOIN will be needed and there might be no need in joining three tables and I might have to use IN or EXISTS. However, I am having a rough time determining how to write the query. Can someone please help? Thanks!

Comment: You don't clearly say what you want, how output is a function of input. When you are clear, this will be a faq. Left join is for when you have input rows unmatched by join that you want returned extended by columns with NULL values. To return only one of each row that is the same in every column as input, use select distinct.. Before considering posting please read your textbook and/or manual & google any error message or many clear, concise & precise phrasings of your question/problem/goal, with & without your particular strings/names & site:stackoverflow.com & tags; read many answers. [ask]

Comment: Please in code questions give a [mre]--cut & paste & runnable code, including smallest representative example input as code; desired & actual output (including verbatim error messages); tags & versions; clear specification & explanation. Give the least code you can give that is code that you show is OK extended by code that you show is not OK. (Debugging fundamental.) For SQL that includes DBMS & DDL (including constraints & indexes) & input as code formatted as a table. [ask] Stop trying to code your overall goal & explain what you expected instead from the given code & why.

Answer (score 0):

Well, you could put all products of the same `username` on the same row with aggregation:

```
select u.username, group_concat(product_name) product_names
from users u 
inner join product_to_users ptu on ptu.user_id = u.user_id 
inner join product p on p.security_id = ptu.security_id
group by u.user_id, u.username
```